DC-DC Inverter Battery Charger using a buck Converter
I'm in quite a situation
I have a 220Ah inverter battery.
I was hoping to charge it with 14v 15A approximately 210W which I would get from a buck converter.
I bought the converter from AliExpress here is a link to the item
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003993338821.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.5.37241802dx4Fku. The previous converter was low power and burnt regularly, I can't afford an AC-DC inverter to charge the battery.
It's supposed to be stepping down 19V 9A approximately 170W, I get this power from some laptop chargers. I have being using it for over 2 years no issues.
It came yesterday and I hooked it up to my system and tested the current output on the battery side and it's about 13.5V and less than 2A, I was hoping to get upwards of 10A.
What can I do to improve my system? and to get high power outputs?

Show us a diagram of your setup, where and how you measured, datasheets, etc.

I would check two things: are your wires thin so its voltage drops down to 13.5V when loaded with the battery and is it getting hot so it throttles its current down to 2A to prevent burning out. So, you might need thicker wires or additional cooling (like attaching the converter to a larger aluminum heatsink). It could also be that some specifications are fake or that your converter is one of the lower power ones.

that's simply not a battery charger, don't use it as one if you care about the battery. The linked buck converter expects more than 30V, or more than 60V (depending on what part of the listing you read), so it's behavior when fed only 19V is unpredictable. You need a power supply that can limit amps and set volts, often referred to as a "lab/bench supply", but there are cheap-ish buck modules with "CC+CV" that would work at least rudimentary.

Why are you buying stuff from Mali-express? It's the same with peebay and shamazon; if you buy electrical stuff from them there is no guarantee of quality or performance. Pay a little more and get a data sheet and guaranteed performance from a proper supplier.

@Andyaka for noobs/amateurs/students/teens, discount mail-order places are a godsend. A "real" supplier will charge WAY more than "a little more", especially for low quantities. I recently got a project's parts (esp32 dev board, lm2569 buck module, 16x2 LCD, 4 channel logic-level relay module) all to my door for ~$10... 95% of it is fine, though you should test everything before throwing it in production.

@dandavis what category do you fit into? Noob....to.... pro? What is your experience that leads you to apparently disagree with me?

@Andyaka:  not a pro for sure. If i was i wouldn't gamble on cheap parts. I'm just trying to answer your "why?". It doesn't make sense for tiger woods to use a random ball he found in the woods, but it also doesn't make sense for a 10 year old to fire off Callaway Chrome Softs on a driving range... Price aside, I think many parts/modules are also more discoverable on mass-market sites, and there's often application info in the listing. Ex: a buck module with CC will often have "charging" or "bench" in the title. Digikey doesn't tell you what anything does, just (exactly) what it is.

You are missing my point.

Looks like a buck converter without CC limit. This will not work for charging a battery. Buy a battery charger instead.

There are losses in the system you didn't accounted for. Also, that converter is not adjustable. Batteries that size can demand as much as 50A when charging, so if you can't limit your charge current, it will simply overload your buck. You need a current limited and voltage limited version, adjustable by two potentiometers.( search for this on Aliexpress > 300W 20A DC-DC Buck Converter Step Down Module Constant Current LED Driver Power Step Down Voltage Module Electrolytic Capacitor) I have a similar solar charger system with a buck converter.You need higher voltage on the input side of the converter ( I am using 36V, charging @13.5V@20A max ). Also, as others mentioned...check your input voltage at max output current..it may drop below the specs...and also was a good advice to use thick wires as much as possible. I am using 6mm2 wires between the buck and the battery ( rated at 55A ). Adjust the output voltage of your buck while measuring it. Then ramp up the current limiter, but only to 15A while measuring acutal current.

It's safer (for the device) to set current by adjusting the PSU to 1v, shorting the leads, and adjusting for the current, then unshort and set the voltage. This ensures your current isn't set too high when you first connect the PSU.

@dandavis Yes, I agree it's the best practice
